# How do I download videos from my phone (or card) to my PC?

Tags: usb

How do I download videos from my phone (or card) to my PC? Once I connect the phone and PC only my photos are visible on the PC screen.  I can only see the videos on my phone screen.

Comment: What phone are you using? What Android version does it have? Where did these videos come from: did you record them with the Camera app?

Comment: My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S 5.  Not sure what you mean by "what Android version".  As you may have guessed I am not exactly techno savvy!  I recorded the videos with the camera app, I guess.  Hit the camera button on the phone and selected the little video icon....

Answer (score 1):

Lisa, when you say download I assume that you mean transfer. I apologize, I cannot add comments.

The easiest method I would suggest is that you first go into your File Manager (or download one), and find the path to your videos, e.g. DCIM > 100Media and confirm that your videos are there (or wherever they are). Once achieved, connect your phone and set the USB type to Transfer (or whatever it is called on your device), then navigate to this path on your PC. You should then be able to copy the videos.

Alternatively, let's say your video is called 'video1.mp4', you should then be able to search on your PC for this file. From there, right click and open file location. From there it should just be a matter of copying and pasting. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I will look for the File Manager.  I frequently transfer photographs (so I know the process) but the video will be a first.

Comment: In looking for the File Manager (which I didn't find), I found a tutorial on my phone and I have gotten the videos transferred.  Thank you all!

Comment: Lisa there are several apps- Astro File Manager etc that will help. As long as all works, happy days! Sorry to bother you, but if my answer deemed appropriate please mark it so.

Comment: Reviewing this question, have you been able to answer this question? If my answer suffices please mark it so, if you have the solution please answer your own question of let us know if it is still not solved.